# what options can be passed to flashing in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hello there Grammarians,

The documentation only shows:

> `flashing("success")`

Do failures never happen if I use `play`? I've tried "`failure`" & "`error`" they don't do anything

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Flash

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass in a `Flash` instance or tuples of `String`s. It doesn't have to be a specific `String`. Important is that you handle whatever you stick into the flash scope.

consider this example (Play 2.3.4):

Application.scala

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action { implicit req =>
    Redirect(routes.Application.flash()).flashing("something" -> "show this text")
  }

  def flash = Action { implicit req =>
    Ok(views.html.index("Flash!"))
  }

}
```

index.scala.html

```
@(title: String)(implicit flash: Flash)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>@title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>@flash.get("something")</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

routes

```
# Home page
GET        /                    controllers.Application.index
GET        /flash               controllers.Application.flash
```